# how to drag a div and drop into 4 other divs using jQuery. once i drop into the div 0ne i want to drag the the dragDiv next div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to drag a div and drop into 4 other divs using jQuery. once i drop into the div 0ne i want to drag the the dragDiv next div.

```
<div id="dragdiv"> </div> 

<div id="dropDivone"> </div> 
<div id="dropDivtwo"> </div> 
<div id="dropDivthree"> </div> 
<div id="dropDivfour"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand your question, but if you want to achieve drag & drop functionality  refer to JQuery UI draggable/droppable: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#default. Please analyze examples there.